# Как сделать эффект обтекания текста картинкой?

Tags: android, java

Говорят, как-то можно сделать эффект align как в html. Только то же самое надо в Андроид как-то сделать.

Не подскажите, как сделать эффект, чтобы текст обтекал картинку. Типо слева ImageView, справа и снизу TextView. Ну компоненты закинуть не беда. Как распределить текст по 1 и 2 TextView?

Comment: Такой же вопрос. http://hashcode.ru/questions/388472/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-flowtextview

Comment: обтекания текста картинкой? o_O

Comment: Обтекание картинки текстом))).

Да перешел по ссылке http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2. но там Релиатив и один ImagevIew и TextView. А мне надо было попроще, чтобы 2 TextView было... Чтоб разделить текст на 2 TextView

Comment: @ANDRO, а не xTIGERx ли ты часом?

Comment: @Kaminsky, не понял вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в XML TextView добавить вот это:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/название-файла-картинки-из-ресурсов"
```

Можно и в коде

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (R.id.имя-файла-картинки, 0, 0, 0);
```

**UPD_0:**

Сам я так не пробовал, как выше написал. Если не обтекает, сделайте как тут написано: [тык](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2).

Если вкратце:

Начиная с версии Android 2.2 (api 8) можно юзать интерфейс **LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2**, коий позволяет делать отступ в **n** пикселей для первых **n** строк **первого** абзаца. По ссылке - подробное описание, пример и эта картинка:

[image]

Гуглится это за минуту на запрос:

> image in textview android float

Коий выдаёт [ссыль](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image) , содержащую ссыль на вышележащее решение.

Comment: Отлично)) только обтекания нету...
![asdd](http://snag.gy/qM2fu.jpg)

Comment: @ANDRO, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

FlowTextView вам в помощь [тык](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)